# Prove that for any real numbers $a,b$ we have $\lvert \arctan a−\arctan b\rvert\leq \lvert a−b\rvert$.

Tags: calculus

Prove that for any real numbers  $a,b$ we have  $\lvert \arctan a−\arctan b\rvert\leq \lvert a−b\rvert$. This should have an application of the mean value theorem.

Comment: What is the derivative of $\arctan x$? What does the mean value theorem say about $$\frac{\arctan{a}-\arctan{b}}{a-b}?$$?

Comment: I will give a bigger hint. Take your function to be $\arctan$ and consider it at $a$ and $b$. Mean value theorem tells us that there exists $c$ such that ... ? then use the hint above.

Answer (score 3):

You want to prove that $\lvert \arctan a−\arctan b\rvert\leq \lvert a−b\rvert$. This is equivalent to proving that 
$$
\frac{\lvert \arctan a−\arctan b\rvert}{\lvert a−b\rvert}\leq 1.
$$
Now let $f(x) = \arctan(x)$. Then (make a note of why you can say this) by the Mean Value Theorem you have a $c\in (a,c)$ such that 
$$
f'(c) = \frac{\lvert \arctan a−\arctan b\rvert}{\lvert a−b\rvert}.
$$
All that is left for you to do is to prove that for any such $c$, $f'(c)\leq 1$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$
  \left|\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}x}\arctan(x)\right|~=~\left|\frac{1}{1+x^2}\right|~\leq~ 1
$$
and this ensures that $\arctan (x)$ is [Lipschitz-continuous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity) with Lipschitz constant $1$...

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x)=\arctan x$, then by mean value theorem there exist $c\in (a,b)$ such that

$$|f(a)-f(b)|=f^{\prime}(c) |a-b|$$

$$f^{\prime}(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}\leq1$$

So $f^{\prime}(c)\leq1$ and $|\arctan a-\arctan b|\leq |a-b|$.