# Show that ${\lvert cos(a) - cos(b) \rvert \le \lvert a - b \rvert} $ for any real numbers $a,b$

Tags: calculus

I have to use the mean value theorem to prove this. I'll include my attempt below, for which I used thepost at the very bottom of this question as a guide. If my answer is correct could someone give me a hint about why we needed $f'(c)$ to prove this? Thank you.

${0 \le\lvert cos(a) - cos(b) \rvert \le 1}$

and $\lvert a - b \rvert \ge 0$
 $$f(x) = cos(x)$$ and $$ f'(x) = \lvert-sin(x)\rvert$$
$0\le\lvert-sin(x)\rvert \le 1$

Thus, $f'(c) \le 1$

By the MVT, $${ {\lvert cos(b) - cos(a) \rvert} = f'(c){(b - a)}} $$
and $${\lvert cos(a) - cos(b) \rvert \le \lvert a - b \rvert} $$ for any real numbers $a,b$

[Prove that for any real numbers $a,b$ we have $\lvert \arctan a−\arctan b\rvert\leq \lvert a−b\rvert$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/341741/prove-that-for-any-real-numbers-a-b-we-have-lvert-arctan-a%E2%88%92-arctan-b-rvert)

Comment: The mean value theorem gives an $f'(c)$ to the computation, all we do is bound it. Because you are using the MVT, you have to work with $f'(c)$. Of course, your answer is fine.

Comment: You have some errors in the use of the absolute value signs but your idea is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $(\cos )'=-\sin .$  By the MVT there exists $c$ in the closed interval whose endpoints are $a,b,$ such that $$\cos a -\cos b=(a-b)(\cos )'(c)$$  implying $\;|\cos a -\cos b|=|a-b|\cdot |(\cos)'(c)|=|a-b|\cdot |-\sin c|\leq |a-b|\cdot 1=|a-b|.$

Much easier than a trigonometric proof without calculus.

Footnote: When $a\ne b$ the MVT says there exists such a $c$ lying strictly between $a$ and $b$ but we did  not need that.

Comment: this was great, I didn't really know what i was doing, but i get it now. thank you :)