# inequality questions involving $\arctan$ and $\ln$

Tags: inequality

I have two questions related to inequality:

1) Show that for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace |\arctan(x) - archtan(y)| \leq |x-y|\thinspace\thinspace$ I tried to use the triangle inequality and claim that $|\arctan(x) - arctan(y)| \leq |\arctan(x)| + |\arctan(y)|$ and try to show that $|\arctan(x)| + |\arctan(y)| \leq |x-y|$

2) Why for all $\; x>0$, $\;\ln(x) + \frac{1}{x} \geq0\,?$ How can I show this?

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! What do you denote `archtan`?

Comment: If archtan is a misprint of arctan, then use mean value theorem.

Comment: Please restrict your question to a single problem. – The first one is answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/341741/42969

Comment: @Ak19 If its arctanh then it's obviously wrong.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Yeah, just observed that, so deleted that comment.

Comment: For the second inequality set $x=\dfrac{1}{X}$ : you have now to prove that $-\ln(X)+X>0$... Isn't it evident for any $X>0$ ?

Comment: Sorry for the typo, re-edited it. about the second need more detailed explanation, please.

Comment: I've never seen it called $\operatorname{archtan}$ before, only $\operatorname{artanh}$ or $\operatorname{arctanh}$.

Answer (score 0):

1) The inequality for $\arctan$ is immediate from MVT.

2): $\frac d {dx} (\ln x+\frac 1 x)=\frac  1x -\frac 1 {x^{2}} $ which is negative for $x <1$ and positive for $x>1$. Hence $\ln x+\frac 1 x$ is decreasing in $(0,1)$ and increasing in $(1,\infty)$ so its minimum value is attained at $x=1$. The minimum value is $1$ so we actually get $\ln x+\frac 1 x \geq 1$ for all $x >0$.

Comment: See as well the elementary solution I propose in a comment.

Comment: @JeanMarie OP is asking for a detailed proof. I suspect that OP would ask for  details for $-\ln x +x >0$ also.

Answer (score 0):

(b) Considering only x>0, since y = 1/x has a line of symmetry y = x, the curve of y=1/x going *up* (near the y-axis) is the "same" as the curve of y = 1/x going *right* (near the x-axis). So question (b) is the same as: prove that e^-x < 1/x (1) for all x > 0.

But for all real a > 0 and b > 0, a < b iff 1/a > 1/b (See something like Rudin's PMA Chapter 1 for a proof of this).

So (1) is the same as: prove that e^x > x for all x > 0. For this, see here:

[How to prove that $e^x=x$ has no real solution?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1985849/how-to-prove-that-ex-x-has-no-real-solution/1985858)